# tcl-selenium webdriver: Composite xpath search fails

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, tcl, selenium-chromedriver

I am having difficulty creating a composite xpath with contains call.
But splitting them up works fine.

Whats not working:

```
$window element by_xpath {//div[@class="frost-application-bar "]/*[text()[contains(., "Network")]}
```

and

```
$window element by_xpath {//div[@class="frost-application-bar "]//*[text()[contains(., "Network")]}

>set token [eval "::http::geturl http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/1aaacf7a-460e-4042-9898-722402b5ef76/window  -type application/json -query {{ "name": "CDwindow-70BE1451-D49B-4D23-B853-7EA9A48C3167" }}"]
>set token [eval "::http::geturl http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/1aaacf7a-460e-4042-9898-722402b5ef76/window_handle  -type application/json "]
>set token [eval "::http::geturl http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/1aaacf7a-460e-4042-9898-722402b5ef76/element  -type application/json -query {{ "using": "xpath", "value": "//div[@class=\"frost-application-bar \"]//*[text()[contains(., \"Network\")]" }}"]
>::invalidSelectorError19
```

Whats working

```
$window element by_xpath {//div[@class="frost-application-bar "]}
::WebDriver::Session::webElement211 descendant by_xpath {//*[text()[contains(., "Network")]]}
::WebDriver::Session::webElement212 click
```

Comment: Are those lines prefixed by `>` output from the program? If not, there's some big issues there. (If they are, the issues are in the tcl-selenium code, and shouldn't be your concern right now…)

Comment: There is an unmatched left bracket in the first expression.

Comment: Thanks Peter - there is an unmatched bracket and this fixes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mismatched square bracket at the end. Should be:

```
$window element by_xpath {//div[@class="frost-application-bar "]/*[text()[contains(., "Network")]]}
```